# Saving information regarding a sparse checkout in GitHub

Tags: git, github, sparse-checkout

I have a sparse checkout folder in a project stored in /root. Its checking out the folder `https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/angularjs`

```
/root
/.git
  /todoMVCDemos
    /angular
     /examples/angularjs
     /.git
```

I done this via:

```
git init <repo>
cd <repo>
git remote add origin <url>
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo "examples/angularjs/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull --depth=1 origin master
```

I want to be able to save this information in my repo so another developer can use it. How do I go about this? If I run git status there is nothing to checkin.

For bonus points I don't want the cloned files to be stored under '/examples/angularjs' but rather just in the /angular folder.